# Translation of alphabet used in Konosuba

Tags: konosuba

Is there a complete translation of the "letters" used in the world of Konosuba? I'm talking like the ones seen on their adventurer cards. I'm positive each symbol corresponds to a letter of the English alphabet, but I want the complete list of them if possible?

Here's Megumin's card:

[image: Megumin's adventurer card]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An enterprising person [over here](http://www.matolabel.net/archives/53312283.html) has provided a translation table for the letters and some of the numbers, in multiple typefaces:

[image: Konosuba translation table]

Someone somewhere may have put together a more complete version; this version is from just after episode 3 or 4, and more sourcetext became available as the show went on.

As you surmise, there is a simple one-to-one relationship between the English alphabet (and related glyphs like punctuation and numbers) and the *KonoSuba* alphabet. However, beware: the actual text that is enciphered is not necessarily in the English language - some of it is also in romanized Japanese. For example, someone in the linked thread deciphered this part of your image:

[image: EXPLOSION]

As this:

```
koumazokunonakademouiitsunotensaimahoutsukai. b
akurestumahoutoyobarerusaikyomahounomiruyokunimor
itsukare. soreshikatsukawanaishitukawanai
```

Which may seem like gibberish, but in (somewhat typo-laden) Japanese, it's Megumin babbling about EXPLOSION. Roughly, "A wunderkind magician, even moreso than the average Crimson Demon. She is enraptured by the mightiest of magicks: EXPLOSION. She won't use any other magic, and plus - she *can't*." This particular text is cobbled together from various bits of copy about her character, as far as I know.